# Displaying the value of a specific attribute for a certain product in magento shows error

Tags: php, attributes, magento-1.5

I’m trying to display the value of a particular attribute for certain products, **but the output is being displayed as ‘No’**. I have tried these two ways, but I had no luck.

**$color=($product->getResource()->getAttribute(’color’)->getFrontend()->getValue($product));
$shipping= $product->getAttributeText(’package_id’);**

I have no clue how to overcome this. I don’t know whether I have to change any thing with the configuration settings since I get the output just saying ‘No’ . Please please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get attribute frontend value then just try this

```
nl2br($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product))
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: hi mufaddal, still it displays 'No' for the values. I'm struggilg with this? Have you got any other idea?

Comment: hi mufaddal, I forgot to clear my cache and your solution works great. I could get this done in the product pages view.phtml, but I couldn't work it out in the cart sidebar.phtml Do you have any idea how I can get that there?

Comment: you can use this code anywhere if you load prodcut object properly,if you load product in cart page then this code works for you

Comment: Hiya, you are right, I didn't load the product properly. now it works cool. Thanks once again.